# Why do UIScreen dimensions differ on iOS device and simulator?

Tags: ios, swift, screen, scale, uiscreen

In troubleshooting an app I'm developing, I discovered that the UIScreen.main.bounds.width differs between my iPhone 8 Plus real device vs the simulator. To narrow it down, I created a new Swift app from the iOS App template in Xcode 13.4.1 targetting iOS 15.5 and added one line of code in `viewDidLoad()`:

```
print("\(UIScreen.main.bounds.width)x\(UIScreen.main.bounds.height)")
```

Running on the simulator I get the expected dimensions:

```
414.0x736.0
```

but on my device I get:

```
375.0x667.0
```

I can't figure out why the difference. Past answers on this topic talk about Launch Screen images and whatnot, but my understanding is that all went away with the Launch Storyboard which this default template is using.

BTW, deleting the Launch Storyboard from the project results in dimensions of 320x480 which is expected as the app drops back to "scaled mode". So I don't think that's a factor here.

Definitely an iPhone 8 plus:

[Settings|General|About](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UglqL.png)

Comment: Sounds like you don't actually have an `iPhone 8 Plus`. On your physical phone, open the Settings app, select General, select About... and not the Model Name and Model Number.

Comment: Yes, it looks like you have an iPhone 8, not an 8 plus https://www.ios-resolution.com/

Comment: @DonMag Definitely an iPhone 8 Plus

Comment: @grosssw - what is the Model Number?

Comment: @DonMag MQ992LL/A

Comment: Settings | Display & Brightness | Display Zoom was on. Turning it off fixed my issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Settings | Display & Brightness | Display Zoom was on. Turning it off fixed my issue.